# Nonlinear PDE in COMSOL

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve an elliptic, "Poisson-like," fully nonlinear PDE via the finite element method. I have formerly used FreeFEM++ to do this, but would now like to use COMSOL, if this is possible. After reading the documentation, I still have no idea how to proceed.

My method proceeds as:
1. Solve a poisson equation boundary value problem for $u_0$. The domain for all of this can just be the unit square by the way (which I also have no idea how to attain). 
2. Use this solution $u_0$ as initial guess in the iterative problem, a weak form of poisson problem, $\int_{\Omega} \nabla u_{k+1} \cdot \nabla v ~dx = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_{k} \cdot \nabla v ~dx+F(u_k)$, for $k=0,1,...$, and where $F$ involves some stuff nonlinear in $u_k$. In addition, I need my $F(u_k)$ to include both averages and jumps across elements (it's some penalty method). So, lots of questions here, any help appreciated.